# ldconfig Not Found

Tags: linux, dpkg

My system is messed up and I dont understand whats going on. Whenever I try to install any package, it tells me to run "sudo apt-get -f install" . I guess this is because I tried to install some package without its dependencies. And when I run that command, it say ldconfig not found. I dont know why it says so. I get the following error.

> dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable. dpkg:
>   error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable. Note:
>   root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and
>   /sbin.

When I try to locate ldconfig, I see it as folder only in var/cache/.
Path is set as follows.

> anup@ubuntu:~$ echo $PATH
>   /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/var/cache

Please suggest!

Comment: Likely you have almost killed your linux :) Usually it resides in `/sbin/`.

Comment: please suggest a solution

Comment: Best solution (for a newbie like you) is to re-install a distribution after having backed up your `/etc` and your `/home` on some external media

Answer (score 4):

Well, there're a few possible steps for recover.

Manually unpack the content of `libc-bin` package. The package can be downloaded from here http://ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/eglibc/ and you should choose a version suitable for your Ubuntu version. Please consult the following page http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/libc-bin and see what version you need.

To unpack you may use `ar` and `tar` utilities:

```
    mkdir /tmp/a_new_directory; cd /tmp/a_new_directory
    ar x /path/to/libc-bin-<version>.deb data.tar.gz
    tar zxf data.tar.gz
```

Then you need the unpacked copy of `ldconfig` to /sbin/. Also you probably need other files from the archive, check what you currently have in your hard drive.

After you restore the basic functionality of your installation, I would recommend to re-install all the packages from the base system, those marked as essential :)

Comment: Thanks will follow that I will let you know.

Comment: In the worst case remember: Ubuntu is easy to re-install from scratch :)

Comment: I did this and it worked for me, nice!